# Auth::user on Laravel with different table

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have two additional column for login with different tables. So, I used 3 tables for login with output like this:

[image]

When I want to use username its simply write it like this {{ Auth::user()->username }} so I get value KASIR WEB. But it not work with kd_lokasi and kd_shift. Where I should register it? Or how I can get kd_lokasi and kd_shift value and paste it on view? Thank you for helping me.

Table :

```
    $kd_lokasi = DB::table("tb_kasir_lokasi")->where("vTampil", 1)->get()
        ->pluck("nm_lokasi", "kd_lokasi");

    $kd_shift = DB::table("tb_kasir_shift")->where("vTampil", 1)->get()
        ->pluck("nm_shift", "kd_shift");
```

Comment: Did you use different models or add the columns to the users table? If they are in the users table, they will be loaded with the user model and `Auth::user()->kd_shift` should work

Comment: You need to call with guard `Auth::guard('admin')->user();` , but first you need to configure `config/auth.php`

Comment: They aren't in the users table, I use it with query builder. I tried {{Auth::user()->kd_shift}} but not working.

Comment: What is the database table structure, can you provide details of table structure which table contains which fields and also their respective models

Comment: I don't know if its a problem or not but I don't use Model for kd_shift and kd_lokasi, I use query builder instead. Please kindly check this post, added table structure there.